# C++ Unable to decompress messages returning from WebSocket API(Okex) through the inflate algorithm

Tags: c++

I am trying to decompress message returning from WebSocket API(Okex). I tried to use zlib to decompress but fails. Please advise how to do so.

The following are websocket class written to connect to okex and returning data from the websocket server.

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>


typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;
typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;

using websocketpp::lib::bind;

void on_open(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    std::string msg = "{\"op\": \"subscribe\", \"args\": [\"spot/depth5:ETH-USDT\"]}";
    c->send(hdl,msg,websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
    c->get_alog().write(websocketpp::log::alevel::app, "Sent Message: "+msg);
}

void websocketClient::on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg) {
    std::cout << msg->get_payload().size()<< std::endl;
    std::cout << msg->get_payload().data()<< std::endl;

    string str = utility::inflationAlgorithm::decompress(msg->get_payload());
}

websocketClient::websocketClient() {
    client c;
    std::string uri = "wss://real.okex.com:8443/ws/v3";
    try {
        // Set logging to be pretty verbose (everything except message payloads)
        c.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        c.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);
        // Initialize ASIO
        c.init_asio();
        c.set_tls_init_handler(bind(&on_tls_init));

        // Register our message handler
        c.set_open_handler(bind(&on_open, &c,::_1));
        c.set_message_handler(bind(&websocketClient::on_message,this,::_1,::_2));
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
        websocketClient::con = c.get_connection(uri, ec);

        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "could not create connection because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }else {
            c.connect(websocketClient::con);

            // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
            // this will cause a single connection to be made to the server. c.run()
            // will exit when this connection is closed.

            c.run();


        }
    } catch (websocketpp::exception const & e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The following code are written to decompress the message returning from Okex, but unable to get decompressed string.

```
#include <sstream>
#include "inflationAlgorithm.h"

using namespace zlibcomplete;
using namespace std;
std::string utility::inflationAlgorithm::decompress(const std::string & str)
{
    z_stream zs;                        // z_stream is zlib's control structure
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

    if (inflateInit2(&zs, 47) != Z_OK)
        throw(std::runtime_error("inflateInit failed while decompressing."));

    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)str.data();
    zs.avail_in = (uint)str.size();

    int ret;
    char outbuffer[32768];
    std::string outstring;

    // get the decompressed bytes blockwise using repeated calls to inflate
    do {
        zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(outbuffer);
        zs.avail_out = sizeof(outbuffer);

        ret = inflateInit2(&zs, 47);
        if (outstring.size() < zs.total_out) {
            outstring.append(outbuffer,
                             zs.total_out - outstring.size());
        }

    } while (ret == Z_OK);
    inflateEnd(&zs);
    if (ret != Z_STREAM_END) {          // an error occurred that was not EOF
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Exception during zlib decompression: (" << ret << ") "
            << zs.msg;
        throw(std::runtime_error(oss.str()));
    }


    return outstring;
}
```